# Solving a nonlinear systems of coupled differential equations with boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am trying to solve the following systems of coupled differential equations with boundary conditions (BC) at $0$ and at $∞$ :

$y_{1}'(x)=\frac{-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\,\frac{\alpha}{18}\,x^4+x\,y_{2}(x)}{\frac{\alpha}{6}+\frac{x^3}{3}y_{4}(x)+\frac{1}{3}y_{3}(x)+\frac{2}{5}y_{5}'(x)+\frac{6}{5\,x}y_{5}(x)}y_{1}(x)$
BC : $y_{1}(0)=1 \;;\; y_{1}(\infty)=0$

$y_{2}'(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\,x^2\,y_{1}(x)$
BC : $y_{2}(0)=0\; ; \;y_{2}(\infty)=1$

$y_{3}'(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\,x^4\,y_{1}(x)$
BC : $y_{3}(0)=0\; ;\; y_{3}(\infty)=3$

$y_{4}'(x)=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\,x\,y_{1}(x)$
BC : $y_{4}(\infty)=0$

$\frac{\alpha}{4} \left[\frac{4}{3} x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{1}{x^4}\frac{\partial y_{1}(x)}{\partial x})+\frac{2}{5}\frac{1}{x^7}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(x^3 y_{5}(x)\right)\right]+\frac{27}{35}\frac{\alpha}{x^4}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[x^3 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{y_{5}(x)}{x^2})\right]-\frac{3}{x^3}y_{5}(x)=0$
BC : $y_{5}(0)=0\; ;\; y_{5}(\infty)=0$

Where $\alpha$ are know constants : $\alpha=0.001$

The mathematica code is:

```
NDSolve[{y1'[x]==((-Sqrt[(2/Pi)] alpha/18 x^4+x y2[x])/(alpha/6+6/5 1/x y5[x]+2/5 y5'[x]+ y3[x]/3+( x^3 y4[x])/3))y1[x],
y2'[x]==Sqrt[2/Pi] x^2 y1[x],
y3'[x]==Sqrt[2/Pi] x^4 y1[x],
y4'[x]==-Sqrt[(2/Pi)]x y1[x],
-(3/x^3)y5[x]+alpha/4 (4/ 3 x D[1/ (x^4) y1'[x],x]+2/ 5 1/ (x^7) D[x^3 y5[x],x])+alpha/4 36/ 7 1/ (x^4) D[3/ 5 x^3 D[1/ (x^2) y5[x],x],x]==0,y1[0]==1,y2[Infinity]==1,y3[Infinity]==3,y4[Infinity]==0,y5[Infinity]==0},{y1,y2,y3,y4,y5},{x,0,10},Method->{"Shooting","StartingInitialConditions"->{y1[0]==1,y2[Infinity]==1,y3[Infinity]==3,y4[Infinity]==0,y5[Infinity]==0}}]
```

I get the following output:

```
NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations. >>

NDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable y1^\[Prime]. >>
```

Please, How can I find solutions of these differential equations?

Answer (score 3):

Some progress can be made by noting that `NDSolve` cannot handle undefined alpha and boundary conditions at infinity, and that `y5` appears nowhere in the first four ODEs and therefore can be decoupled from the other equations.  It also makes sense to shoot from large `x`, because three of the four boundary conditions are there.  So, we might try

```
xmax = 2.1; 
sol = NDSolve[{y1'[x] == ((-Sqrt[(2/π)] alpha/18 x^4 + x y2[x])/
    (alpha/6 + y3[x]/3 + (x^3 y4[x])/3)) y1[x], 
    y2'[x] == Sqrt[2/π] x^2 y1[x], y3'[x] == Sqrt[2/π] x^4 y1[x], 
    y4'[x] == -Sqrt[(2/π)] x y1[x], y1[0] == 1, y2[xmax] == 1, 
    y3[xmax] == 3, y4[xmax] == 0} /. alpha -> 10^-3,
    {y1, y2, y3, y4}, {x, 0, xmax}, Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y1[xmax] ==.68477, 
    y2[xmax] == 1, y3[xmax] == 3, y4[xmax] == 0}}];
```

which produces the solution,

```
Plot[Evaluate[{y1[x], y2[x], y3[x], y4[x]} /. sol], {x, 0, xmax}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, `y1[xmax]` is not close to zero, suggesting that `xmax` has been chosen as too small a number.

So, what value of `xmax` is appropriate?  To find out, solve for and plot the asymptotic solutions.

```
asym = FullSimplify[First@DSolve[{y1'[x] == ((-Sqrt[(2/π)] alpha/18 x^4)/(alpha/6)) y1[x], 
    y2'[x] == Sqrt[2/π] x^2 y1[x], y3'[x] == Sqrt[2/π] x^4 y1[x], 
    y4'[x] == -Sqrt[(2/π)] x y1[x]}, {y1[x], y2[x], y3[x], y4[x]},x] 
    /. {C[2] -> 1, C[3] -> 3, C[4] -> 0}, x > 0];
Plot[Evaluate[{y1[x], y2[x], y3[x], y4[x]} //. 
    Flatten[{C[1] -> 1, asym}]], {x, 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

(`C[1] -> 1` is an arbitrary choice.)  To see where the asymptotic result is accurate, plot the error in the original first equation, when the asymptotic solutions are inserted.

```
Plot[Evaluate[(y1'[x] - ((-Sqrt[(2/π)] alpha/18 x^4 + x y2[x])/(alpha/6 + y3[x]/3 + 
    (x^3 y4[x])/3)) y1[x]) //. Flatten[{alpha -> 10^-3, C[1] -> 1, asym, 
     y1'[x] -> D[First@asym[[1,2]], x]}] // Simplify], {x, 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {x, err}]
```

[image]

We see, therefore, that `xmax = 3` would be a good choice for `NDSolve`.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a good `Shooting` guess to obtain numerical solutions for `xmax > 2.1`.  Thus, the plots above provide a qualitative picture of the solution, but not a quantitative one.

Comment: Thank you @bbgodfrey. But I did not understand why at `x=xmax`, `y1[xmax] == 0.68477` and not `y1[xmax] ==0` as mentioned in the BC of `y1`. Namely, `y1` is a Maxwellian solution.

Comment: @Betatron  `y1[xmax]` is not close to zero, because `xmax` is too small.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to obtain a solution for the more appropriate `xmax = 3`.  The challenge is handling the possibility that `alpha/6 + y3[x]/3 + x^3 y4[x]/3` may vanish somewhere.  I continue to think about this issue.  By the way, your question states that both `y2` and `y3` vanish at the origin.  Are you confident that using those boundary conditions instead of the corresponding ones at large `x` would yield the same answer?

Comment: Sorry @bbgodfrey. I made a mistake in the first differential equation. It's missing `y5`. Normally : `y1'[x]==((-Sqrt[(2/Pi)] alpha/18 x^4+x y2[x] )/(alpha/6+6/5 1/x y5[x]+2/5 y5'[x]+ y3[x]/3+( x^3 y4[x])/3)) y1[x]` where `y5` satisfy the the fifth equation :  `-(3/ (x^3))y5[x]+alpha/4 (4/ 3 x D[1/ (x^4) y1'[x],x]+2/ 5 1/ (x^7) D[x^3 y5[x],x])+alpha/4 36/ 7 1/ (x^4) D[3/ 5 x^3 D[1/ (x^2) y5[x],x],x]==0`. Thank you. Again, I apologize.

Comment: @Betatron  To make any headway, you need to change dependent variables, so that only one second-derivative appears in the fifth ODE.  In addition, you need to define alpha in the code and replace `Infinity` by `10` (or whatever upper bound of integration you choose).  Even then, the first ODE creates great problems.

Comment: @Betatron Have you made any progress on this question?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Unfortunately no any progress.